# Configure Move_Base_Flex parameters

Tags: ros, teb-local-planner

First of all I am a completly beginner in ROS, so I would appreciate your easy explanations...

I am trying to configurate Move_Base_flex. It is an eassy path to be followed, with no obstacles . It is just a robot going throw a broccoli field. I am using Teb_local_planner and GlobalPlanner.
The problem seems to be the Teb_local_planer. I think it is just a matter of finding the correct value of each parameter but I am not able to do it... what I have notice is:

- The robot obscilate following a stright line
- It turns really slow
- At certain time it gets crazy and it stops or jump to another line of broccolis.

Beside that, I am using rviz to representate the odometry and the global plan. For some reason, as the robot moves forward, the route already taken by the robot disappears. I would like to take a picture at the end to compare between the path to be followed and the real path followed by the robot. Why does it happend?

This is my repo: https://github.com/julioRF5/Agribot_TFM-MII  I am executing:

- roslaunch agribot_gazebo agribot_farm.launch
- python load_waypoints_moveBase.py
- rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 map odom 100
- roslaunch agribot_navigation agribot_navigation.launch

Thank you so much for the help!!